# Dynamic use of T-SQL schemas

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, stored-procedures

Is there a way which I can omit the schema of objects used in a stored procedure and these objects aren't bound to the schema of stored procedure but the schema of logged used in manner that the same stored procedure produce different results for user in different schemas?

For better understanding what I'm trying to do, below I'll try to explain better.

Supposing the following database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SampleTable01] (...)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SampleTable02] (...)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SampleTable03] (...)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SampleTable04] (...)
```

In this database, the number following the name of the table represents the owner of the table (it is a legacy system and I can't change that).

To integrate that into .net Entity Framework, I come with a solution of creating synonyms in different schemas, so changing the connections string I can change the objects used without changing my database context or my programming logic.

Like this.

```
CREATE SCHEMA [s01]
CREATE SYNONYM [s01].[SampleTable] FOR [dbo].[SampleTable01]

...

CREATE SCHEMA [s04]
CREATE SYNONYM [s04].[SampleTable] FOR [dbo].[SampleTable04]
```

This solutions is working pretty well, but I need to duplicate all the stored procedures used, because the stored procedures are bound to a specific object.

When I create the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_SampleProc] AS
SELECT * FROM [SampleTable]
```

The stored procedure will produce an error, because the `[SampleTable]` doesn't exists in the schema `[dbo]`.

What I'm doing is duplicating the stored procedures to match the schema from the logged user.

So I'm doing this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [s01].[usp_SampleProc] AS
SELECT * FROM [s01].[SampleTable]

...

CREATE PROCEDURE [s04].[usp_SampleProc] AS
SELECT * FROM [s04].[SampleTable]
```

A user in `[s01]` schema will get values from `[s01].[SampleTable]` and a user in `[s04]` schema will get values from `[s04].[SampleTable]`, when executing `[usp_SampleProc]` without specifying the schema, which is my expected result.

So far so good, this isn't productive in my real scenario. I have thousand of tables, hundreds of procedures and dozen of schemas (I know this is ugly, but I integrating a legacy system with .net, and so far, it is the best solution which I come).

So, the question again:

Is there a way which I can omit the schema of objects used in the stored procedure and these objects aren't bound to the schema of the stored procedure but the schema of the logged in user in manner that the same stored procedure produces different results for users in different schemas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the two ways I know to do what I'm trying to do.

Both ways will be transparent to developers, so they won't need to understand the complexity of the solution.

Below I created a sample which everyone can use:

**Original legacy database creation:** remains unchanged, since the legacy applications still using the database.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SampleTable01] (
    value varchar(100)
)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[SampleTable01] VALUES ('[dbo].[SampleTable01]')

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SampleTable02] (
    value varchar(100)
)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[SampleTable02] VALUES ('[dbo].[SampleTable02]')

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SampleTable03] (
    value varchar(100)
)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[SampleTable03] VALUES ('[dbo].[SampleTable03]')

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SampleTable04] (
    value varchar(100)
)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[SampleTable04] VALUES ('[dbo].[SampleTable04]')
GO
```

**User and schema separation used by my application:** those are a lot of duplicated code, but will be generated by the application setup.

```
CREATE SCHEMA [S01]
GO

CREATE SCHEMA [S02]
GO

CREATE SCHEMA [S03]
GO

CREATE SCHEMA [S04]
GO

CREATE USER USER_S01 WITHOUT LOGIN WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = S01
GO

CREATE USER USER_S02 WITHOUT LOGIN WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = S02
GO

CREATE USER USER_S03 WITHOUT LOGIN WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = S03
GO

CREATE USER USER_S04 WITHOUT LOGIN WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = S04
GO

CREATE SYNONYM [S01].[SampleTable] FOR [dbo].[SampleTable01]
CREATE SYNONYM [S02].[SampleTable] FOR [dbo].[SampleTable02]
CREATE SYNONYM [S03].[SampleTable] FOR [dbo].[SampleTable03]
CREATE SYNONYM [S04].[SampleTable] FOR [dbo].[SampleTable04]
GO

GRANT DELETE     ON SCHEMA::[S01] TO [USER_S01]
GRANT EXECUTE    ON SCHEMA::[S01] TO [USER_S01]
GRANT INSERT     ON SCHEMA::[S01] TO [USER_S01]
GRANT REFERENCES ON SCHEMA::[S01] TO [USER_S01]
GRANT SELECT     ON SCHEMA::[S01] TO [USER_S01]
GRANT UPDATE     ON SCHEMA::[S01] TO [USER_S01]
GRANT EXECUTE    ON SCHEMA::[S01] TO [USER_S01]
GO

GRANT DELETE     ON SCHEMA::[S02] TO [USER_S02]
GRANT EXECUTE    ON SCHEMA::[S02] TO [USER_S02]
GRANT INSERT     ON SCHEMA::[S02] TO [USER_S02]
GRANT REFERENCES ON SCHEMA::[S02] TO [USER_S02]
GRANT SELECT     ON SCHEMA::[S02] TO [USER_S02]
GRANT UPDATE     ON SCHEMA::[S02] TO [USER_S02]
GRANT EXECUTE    ON SCHEMA::[S02] TO [USER_S02]
GO

GRANT DELETE     ON SCHEMA::[S03] TO [USER_S03]
GRANT EXECUTE    ON SCHEMA::[S03] TO [USER_S03]
GRANT INSERT     ON SCHEMA::[S03] TO [USER_S03]
GRANT REFERENCES ON SCHEMA::[S03] TO [USER_S03]
GRANT SELECT     ON SCHEMA::[S03] TO [USER_S03]
GRANT UPDATE     ON SCHEMA::[S03] TO [USER_S03]
GRANT EXECUTE    ON SCHEMA::[S03] TO [USER_S03]
GO

GRANT DELETE     ON SCHEMA::[S04] TO [USER_S04]
GRANT EXECUTE    ON SCHEMA::[S04] TO [USER_S04]
GRANT INSERT     ON SCHEMA::[S04] TO [USER_S04]
GRANT REFERENCES ON SCHEMA::[S04] TO [USER_S04]
GRANT SELECT     ON SCHEMA::[S04] TO [USER_S04]
GRANT UPDATE     ON SCHEMA::[S04] TO [USER_S04]
GRANT EXECUTE    ON SCHEMA::[S04] TO [USER_S04]
GO
```

**Solution 1 (my choice):** consists in using same procedure name in different schemas. One procedure for each user (which have its own schemas).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [S01].[usp_SampleProc]
AS
SELECT * FROM [SampleTable]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [S02].[usp_SampleProc]
AS
SELECT * FROM [SampleTable]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [S03].[usp_SampleProc]
AS
SELECT * FROM [SampleTable]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [S04].[usp_SampleProc]
AS
SELECT * FROM [SampleTable]
GO
```

**Solution 2:** uses dynamic created, since in time of execution the table references will be resolved to synonym inside user's schema.

```
GRANT EXECUTE    ON SCHEMA::[dbo] TO [USER_S01]
GRANT EXECUTE    ON SCHEMA::[dbo] TO [USER_S02]
GRANT EXECUTE    ON SCHEMA::[dbo] TO [USER_S03]
GRANT EXECUTE    ON SCHEMA::[dbo] TO [USER_S04]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_SampleProc]
AS
    exec(N'SELECT * FROM [SampleTable]')
GO
```

**Execution:** Exactly the same for both solutions.

```
EXECUTE AS USER = 'USER_S01'
EXEC [usp_SampleProc]
REVERT;

EXECUTE AS USER = 'USER_S02'
EXEC [usp_SampleProc]
REVERT;

EXECUTE AS USER = 'USER_S03'
EXEC [usp_SampleProc]
REVERT;

EXECUTE AS USER = 'USER_S04'
EXEC [usp_SampleProc]
REVERT;
```

**Reason of choice:** I wan't the developer to simplify the creation and test of procedures. And to solve bugs that occurred in production. In the manner I decided to use, the procedure will be exact the same for all schemas. So, will be easy to test a problem that occurs in that schema just by logging with that and solving that for all schemas.

The disadvantage of the solution, is that I can't put schemas in the tables inside procedures. So it will be a minor performance loss.

Answer (score 2):

In some situations you don't really have to choice to rely on Dynamic SQL.

Instead of creating more and more objects, try to dynamically call your table.

It could look something like this :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_SampleProc]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL varchar(MAX)
    set @SQL = 'SELECT col1, col2, ... FROM [SampleTable'+ SUSER_SNAME() +']'
    exec(@SQL)
END
```

You might have to transform the username to fit your naming convention.

Also, you should not use "select *" in this context, since it's not compiled you could end up with some surprise if there is any modification in the table structure.

Comment: I avoid at all cost use dynamically generated sql. It is hard to debug, to maintain. I this case, I prefer duplicated procedures for each schema.

Comment: That is why I don't like using D-SQL myself, but sometimes I prefer to walk down that path instead of creating a highly complex logic that would require much more maintenance in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I'd get very familiar with SqlCmd.exe (command line utility) and using variables.

I'm gonna try to put the code for 5 files below.
I will place a tag before the code (the contents of the file) with the name of the file like this:

|||||||||||||||||||MyFileName.txt|||||||||||||||||||

You will not put this in the contents of the file, but everything below this "marker" line will be the contents of the file.  You need name the files exactly as I have them.  And you will put all files in the same directory.

After you have all the files created, you need to edit the (one) .bat file and update a few pieces of information.  (Mainly, where your sqlcmd.exe exists on your machine, and the name of your sqlserver/instance where you have rights to create a database using integrated authentication.

Here are the common locations:

```
%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\sqlcmd.exe
%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn\sqlcmd.exe
%ProgramFiles% (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn\sqlcmd.exe
```

Let's go!

|||||||||||||||||||MasterRunMeBatFile.bat|||||||||||||||||||

```
REM Find the location of your SQLCMD.EXE
set __sqlCmdLocation=c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\SQLCMD.EXE

REM Set your servername/instancename here
set __sqlServerNameAndInstance=MyServerName\MyInstanceName



REM Create the database
"%__sqlCmdLocation%" -i .\DatabaseCreate.sql -b -S "%__sqlServerNameAndInstance%"  -E -o ".\ZZZ_DatabaseCreateOutput.txt" -v DBName="MyFirstCommandLineDB"


REM Create the multiple Schemas
"%__sqlCmdLocation%" -i .\SchemasCreate.sql -b -S "%__sqlServerNameAndInstance%"  -E -o ".\ZZZ_SchemasCreate_01.txt" -v DBName="MyFirstCommandLineDB" SchemaName="Schema01"
"%__sqlCmdLocation%" -i .\SchemasCreate.sql -b -S "%__sqlServerNameAndInstance%"  -E -o ".\ZZZ_SchemasCreate_02.txt" -v DBName="MyFirstCommandLineDB" SchemaName="Schema02"
"%__sqlCmdLocation%" -i .\SchemasCreate.sql -b -S "%__sqlServerNameAndInstance%"  -E -o ".\ZZZ_SchemasCreate_03.txt" -v DBName="MyFirstCommandLineDB" SchemaName="Schema03"


REM Create the DDL (tables)
"%__sqlCmdLocation%" -i .\OrganizationDDL.sql -b -S "%__sqlServerNameAndInstance%"  -E -o ".\ZZZ_OrganizationDDL_01.txt" -v DBName="MyFirstCommandLineDB" MySchemaVariable="Schema01" MyUniqueNumber="01" DBUSERNAME="public"
"%__sqlCmdLocation%" -i .\OrganizationDDL.sql -b -S "%__sqlServerNameAndInstance%"  -E -o ".\ZZZ_OrganizationDDL_02.txt" -v DBName="MyFirstCommandLineDB" MySchemaVariable="Schema02" MyUniqueNumber="02" DBUSERNAME="public"
"%__sqlCmdLocation%" -i .\OrganizationDDL.sql -b -S "%__sqlServerNameAndInstance%"  -E -o ".\ZZZ_OrganizationDDL_03.txt" -v DBName="MyFirstCommandLineDB" MySchemaVariable="Schema03" MyUniqueNumber="03" DBUSERNAME="public"


REM Create some stored procedures against the multiple schemas
"%__sqlCmdLocation%" -i .\TSQL_USP_UDF_TRG.sql -b -S "%__sqlServerNameAndInstance%"  -E -o ".\ZZZ_TSQL_USP_UDF_TRG_01.txt" -v DBName="MyFirstCommandLineDB" MySchemaVariable="Schema01" MyUniqueNumber="01" DBUSERNAME="public"
"%__sqlCmdLocation%" -i .\TSQL_USP_UDF_TRG.sql -b -S "%__sqlServerNameAndInstance%"  -E -o ".\ZZZ_TSQL_USP_UDF_TRG_02.txt" -v DBName="MyFirstCommandLineDB" MySchemaVariable="Schema02" MyUniqueNumber="02" DBUSERNAME="public"
"%__sqlCmdLocation%" -i .\TSQL_USP_UDF_TRG.sql -b -S "%__sqlServerNameAndInstance%"  -E -o ".\ZZZ_TSQL_USP_UDF_TRG_03.txt" -v DBName="MyFirstCommandLineDB" MySchemaVariable="Schema03" MyUniqueNumber="03" DBUSERNAME="public"



set __sqlCmdLocation=
set __sqlServerNameAndInstance=
```

|||||||||||||||||||DatabaseCreate.sql|||||||||||||||||||

```
Use [master];
GO


if exists (select * from sysdatabases where name='$(DBName)')
BEGIN
        DROP DATABASE [$(DBName)];
END

GO



Create Database $(DBName)
GO
```

|||||||||||||||||||SchemasCreate.sql|||||||||||||||||||

```
Use [$(DBName)]
GO



IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.schemas WHERE name = '$(SchemaName)')
    BEGIN
        -- The schema must be run in its own batch!
        EXEC( 'CREATE SCHEMA $(SchemaName)' );
    END


IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.schemas WHERE name = '$(SchemaName)')
    BEGIN
            PRINT 'SCHEMA $(SchemaName) Exists!' ;
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Oh My : SCHEMA $(SchemaName) does not exist.' ;
    END

GO
```

|||||||||||||||||||OrganizationDDL.sql|||||||||||||||||||

```
Use [$(DBName)]
GO



IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = object_id(N'[$(MySchemaVariable)].[Employee$(MyUniqueNumber)]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1)
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE [$(MySchemaVariable)].[Employee$(MyUniqueNumber)]
    END
GO



CREATE TABLE [$(MySchemaVariable)].[Employee$(MyUniqueNumber)]
(
    EmployeeUUID [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID() , 
    SSN varchar(11) , 
    LastName varchar(24) , 
    FirstName varchar(24) , 
    DateOfBirth smalldatetime 

)

ALTER TABLE [$(MySchemaVariable)].[Employee$(MyUniqueNumber)] ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Employee$(MyUniqueNumber)
PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (EmployeeUUID)

ALTER TABLE [$(MySchemaVariable)].[Employee$(MyUniqueNumber)] ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Employee$(MyUniqueNumber)_SSN_Unique
UNIQUE (SSN)

GRANT SELECT , INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON [$(MySchemaVariable)].[Employee$(MyUniqueNumber)] TO $(DBUSERNAME)
GO


PRINT 'Select * from [$(MySchemaVariable)].[Employee$(MyUniqueNumber)]'
Select * from [$(MySchemaVariable)].[Employee$(MyUniqueNumber)]
```

|||||||||||||||||||TSQL_USP_UDF_TRG.sql|||||||||||||||||||

```
Use [$(DBName)]
GO



GO

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[$(MySchemaVariable)].[uspEmployeeGetAll]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
    DROP PROCEDURE [$(MySchemaVariable)].[uspEmployeeGetAll]
GO


CREATE PROCEDURE [$(MySchemaVariable)].[uspEmployeeGetAll]

AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

SELECT 
    EmployeeUUID , 
    SSN , 
    LastName , 
    FirstName , 
    DateOfBirth
FROM 
    [$(MySchemaVariable)].[Employee$(MyUniqueNumber)] e

SET NOCOUNT OFF

GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON $(MySchemaVariable).[uspEmployeeGetAll] TO $(DBUSERNAME)
GO


IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[$(MySchemaVariable)].[uspEmployeeGetAll]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
    PRINT '[$(MySchemaVariable)].[uspEmployeeGetAll] has been created!'
GO


GO



IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[$(MySchemaVariable)].[uspEmployeeGetByUUID]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
    DROP PROCEDURE [$(MySchemaVariable)].[uspEmployeeGetByUUID]
GO

/*
declare @EmployeeUUID uniqueidentifier
select @EmployeeUUID = NEWID() 
exec [$(MySchemaVariable)].[uspEmployeeGetByUUID] @EmployeeUUID
*/

CREATE PROCEDURE [$(MySchemaVariable)].[uspEmployeeGetByUUID]
@EmployeeUUID uniqueidentifier

AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

SELECT 
    EmployeeUUID , 
    SSN , 
    LastName , 
    FirstName , 
    DateOfBirth
FROM 
    [$(MySchemaVariable)].[Employee$(MyUniqueNumber)] e
WHERE 
    e.EmployeeUUID = @EmployeeUUID 

SET NOCOUNT OFF

GO


GRANT EXECUTE ON $(MySchemaVariable).[uspEmployeeGetByUUID] TO $(DBUSERNAME)
GO


IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[$(MySchemaVariable)].[uspEmployeeGetByUUID]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
    PRINT '[$(MySchemaVariable)].[uspEmployeeGetByUUID] has been created!'
GO
```

=============== END FILES and FILE CONTENTS======================

Ok.

At the end of this exercise.... you should have something like this.

Three Tables: (inside the same database)

```
[Schema01].[Employee01] , 
[Schema02].[Employee02] , 
[Schema03].[Employee03]
```

And stored procedure similar to the below one.
(Note, the schema name of the stored procedure AND the table it pulls from.)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Schema01].[uspEmployeeGetAll]

AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

SELECT 
    EmployeeUUID , 
    SSN , 
    LastName , 
    FirstName , 
    DateOfBirth
FROM 
    [Schema01].[Employee01] e
```

IMHO.
Using sqlcmd.exe with variables is the BEST way to ensure perfect repeatability amongst different environments.

Thoughts from another person:

http://blogs.msdn.com/tomholl/archive/2008/04/29/thoughts-on-being-a-solution-architect.aspx

Minimize the amount of code the developers need to write
Developers are paid to write code, and they are generally excellent at it. However once a developer is assigned a swag of requirements or stories they need to get down to work on those specific requirements, and it's not easy for them to keep up with what everyone else is doing in any level of detail.

This can include discovering synergies between different requirements or opportunities for macro-level code reuse and refactoring. A big part of the architect's job is to pick up on these opportunities as they arise and ensure that developers aren't reinventing the wheel in their own worlds.

Ideally this should result in patterns, components and frameworks that allow the developers to get their requirements done with less code, by concentrating on those parts that are unique.

***EXTRA:***

http://www.yaldex.com/sql_server_tutorial_3/ch06lev1sec5.html

That is how you develop the scripts.
But don't forget to comment out the variable settings (inside the .sql files) because the variables inside the contents of the files take precedence over the variables sent-in via the command line.

Please vote on this issue!

http://connect.microsoft.com/sqlserver/feedback/details/382007/in-sqlcmd

Comment: Full sqlcmd.exe documentation at (for Sql Server 2008 R2) at : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: I'm doing something very similiar to it, generating all the information that is duplicated. Indeed, I afraid of changes be made only in database and not replicated in the generation script. Discipline is very difficult to create.

Comment: Are you saying you don't have your scripts in files....(in source control) and you only edit the contents of procedures(etc) manually?  Youch.  You got bigger issues than prefix-schema-names.  Good luck with all that.

Comment: One file per object :  http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2008/02/02/versioning-databases-views-stored-procedures-and-the-like.aspx

Comment: I'm implementing versioning using one file for each object. It's mandatory for any solution to come. I'm in the project less than a month I have to 'solve' all problems as always. I'm using SVN for versioning of files and an automated script to create database for deploy (test, production and dev).

Comment: Ok!  I "get it".  You're early in the process.  I've been there.  That's what I'm doing right now..."solving" the code dependency issues.  I've now found 3 circular references.  :<   A-->B and B-->A (twice)....and a new situation (for me)......... A-->B   B-->C  and C-->A             (where --> stands for "references").   :<   Good luck cleaning up the mess!